# How to use Python merge or join two pandas dataframe with string

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, merge, outer-join

I want to combine two dataframe's data. Dataframe is string

```
df1=pd.read_csv('test1.csv',encoding='utf8',index_col=['id_df1'],header=0)
df2=pd.read_csv('test2.csv',encoding='utf8',index_col=['id_df2'],header=0)
print(df1)
print(df2)

out:
id_df1  student  contact_person
1       john     Amy
2       jeff     Cindy
3       steven   Bob
4       tina     Amy


id_df2  student  parents_list
1       tina     (Amy) (Bob)
2       steven   (Eric) (Bob)
3       john     (Amy)
4       jeff     (Frank) (Harry)

print(type(df1['contact_person'][0]))
print(type(df2['parents_list'][0]))

out:
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
```

if df1['student']==df2['student'] & df1['contact_person'] match df2['parents_list']
I want to use "outer" method like this:

```
output

    id_df1 id_df2 student contact_person parents
0   1      3      john    Amy            (Amy)
1   3      2      steven  Bob            (Eric) (Bob)
2   4      1      tina    Amy            (Amy) (Bob)
3   2      null   jeff    Cindy          null
4   null   4      jeff    null           (Frank) (Harry)
```

Comment: Why is jeff in the result? I do not see 'c' in parents_list.

Comment: I want to use "outer"

Comment: I update my question,thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be: first in your `df1`, you create a column `bool` if your condition is met:

```
df1['bool'] = df1.apply(lambda row: True if row['contact_person'] in df2['parents_list'][df2['student'] == row['student']].iloc[0] else False,1)
```

Then you can `merge` the one where the condition is met `df_yes` and `append` where it is not met `df_no`:

```
df_yes = df1[df1['bool'] == True].\
         merge(df2, on='student', how = 'left').drop('bool',1)
df_no = df1[df1['bool'] == False].\
        append(df2[df2['student'].isin(df1['student'][df1['bool'] == False])]).drop('bool',1)
```

Finally just `append` both:

```
list_ordered_col = ['id_df1', 'id_df2', 'student', 'contact_person', 'parents_list']
df_output = df_yes.append(df_no)[list_ordered_col ].\
            reset_index(drop=True)
```

Note: it was working with your previous input for the parent_list (when it was a,b,c...)

EDIT: replace `df1['bool']=...` by:

```
def parantes_in_parentList (row, df_list):
    df_parent_list = df_list['parents_list'][df_list['student'] == row['student']]
    if not df_parent_list.empty:
        if row['contact_person'] in df_parent_list.iloc[0]:
            return True
    # return False in all the other case
    return False
df1['bool'] = df1.apply(parantes_in_parentList , args=([df2]),axis=1)
```

Comment: if input are real names (like:Amy,Bob,Cindy) , how to write my code

Comment: @Steven it could work the same way, it's more the column `parents_list` which should be a list (or an iterable). Did you try it with the names and your new input?

Comment: Yes,but i get "IndexError: ('single positional indexer is out-of-bounds', 'occurred at index 3')" when i doing this code "df1['bool'] = df1.apply(lambda row: True if row['contact_person'] in df2['parents_list'][df2['student'] == row['student']].iloc[0] else False,1)"

Comment: @Steven here I assume the problem is that `df2['parents_list'][df2['student'] == row['student']]` is probably empty (which is unexpected with the input you show) and doing `.iloc[0]` raise the error. I'll do an EDIT to prevent this in a minute